# Set difference query using SQL in Excel

Tags: sql, vba, excel

I am using the following SQL query to compare two Excel worksheets (The set difference of both)

```
strSql = "SELECT [CD_CLIENTE], [NM_CLIENTE], [CPF/CNPJ], [DS_DOCUMENTO], [DTVALIDADE] FROM [BaseAnterior$] " & _
         "WHERE NOT EXISTS  ( " & _
            "SELECT * FROM [BaseAtual$] WHERE" & _
                "[BaseAtual$].[CD_CLIENTE] = [BaseAnterior$].[CD_CLIENTE] AND " & _
                "[BaseAtual$].[NM_CLIENTE] = [BaseAnterior$].[NM_CLIENTE] AND " & _
                "[BaseAtual$].[DS_DOCUMENTO] = [BaseAnterior$].[DS_DOCUMENTO] AND " & _
                "[BaseAtual$].[CPF/CNPJ] = [BaseAnterior$].[CPF/CNPJ] AND " & _
                "[BaseAtual$].[DTVALIDADE] = [BaseAnterior$].[DTVALIDADE]" & _
            ")"
```

The statement works fine, the problem is that it is painfully slow. The Worksheets have aprox. 100k records (don't ask me why they are not in a serious database) and the execution can take several minutes. I know that the problem lies on my SQL statement, so my question is: **Is there a faster way to select the set difference in SQL?**

Comment: Not without a proper database, indexing would probably be the best way but again, not in Excel I'm afraid.

Comment: Try `FULL JOIN` them by all fields. Then you can find difference records on both sides.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan could you show me how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First try both sheets order by all columns, then try this:

```
strSql = "SELECT " &_
      "[B1].[CD_CLIENTE], [B1].[NM_CLIENTE], [B1].[CPF/CNPJ], [B1].[DS_DOCUMENTO], [B1].[DTVALIDADE], " &_
      "[B2].[CD_CLIENTE], [B2].[NM_CLIENTE], [B2].[CPF/CNPJ], [B2].[DS_DOCUMENTO], [B2].[DTVALIDADE] " &_
    [FROM BaseAnterior$] [B1] " & _
         "FULL JOIN [BaseAtual$] [B2] " & _
                "ON [B2].[CD_CLIENTE] = [B1].[CD_CLIENTE] AND " & _
                "[B2].[NM_CLIENTE] = [B1].[NM_CLIENTE] AND " & _
                "[B2].[DS_DOCUMENTO] = [B1].[DS_DOCUMENTO] AND " & _
                "[B2].[CPF/CNPJ] = [B1].[CPF/CNPJ] AND " & _
                "[B2].[DTVALIDADE] = [B1].[DTVALIDADE]"
```

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way is probably not to use SQL at all.  Do the following:

1. Sort the records on the two sheets by the list of columns
2. Go down the list and compare record to record

Excel does a pretty good job sorting records.  The comparison should then be very fast.

In the original formulation, each record in one sheet has to be compared to all (well, perhaps half) the records in the other.  This takes a long time.

Comment: I modified my code to use a loop to compare the data and it was much more faster. Simpler is better